# Voigt notation in Mathematica

Tags: tensors

In the computational mechanics software (Abaqus, Ansys, Comsol, etc), Voigt notation is always used to represent a symmetric tensor by reducing its order.

Now I would ask How can we get the Voigt Notation from second order tensor or fourth order tensor in **a very efficient** way in Mathematica.

e.g. second order tensor:

```
Array[Subscript[a, ## & @@ Sort[{##}]] &, {6, 6}] //  MatrixForm
```

PS: 'using hand writing' is not a good way.

Reference Links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voigt_notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that, in general, the elements are ordered in a spiral:

```
ClearAll[voigtSpiral]
voigtSpiral = Module[{indices = Accumulate[
  Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ Transpose[
   {PadRight[{{1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}}, {Length@#, 2}, "Periodic"], 
    Range[Length@#, 1, -1]}]]}, 
 Extract[#, indices]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
array[n_Integer] := Array[Subscript[a, ## & @@ Sort[{##}]] &, {n, n}]

voigtSpiral @ array @ 3 // TeXForm
```

> $\small\left\{a_ {1, 1}, a_ {2, 2}, a_ {3, 3}, a_ {2, 3}, a_ {1, 3}, 
>   a_ {1, 2} \right\}$

```
voigtSpiral @ array @ 6 // TeXForm
```

> $\small\left\{a_{1,1},a_{2,2},a_{3,3},a_{4,4},a_{5,5},a_{6,6},a_{5,6},a_{4,6},a_{3,6},a_{2,6},a_{1,6},a_{1,5},a_{1,4},a_{1,3},a_{1,2},a_{2,3},a_{3,4},a_{4,5},a_{3,5},a_{2,5},a_{2,4}\right\}$

**Visualization:**

```
pathGraph = PathGraph[voigtSpiral @ array @ #, DirectedEdges -> True, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexLabelStyle -> 20, 
    ImagePadding -> 20, VertexShapeFunction -> None, 
    VertexSize -> Scaled[.1], ImageSize -> 350, 
    VertexCoordinates -> (RotationTransform[-Pi/2] @ 
     (voigtSpiral[array @ #] /. Subscript[_, x__] :> {x}))] &;

Grid[Partition[pathGraph /@ Range[2, 7], 3]]
```

[image]

Comment: If I need such a new role:namely { a11,a22,a33,a12,a23,a31}, how can I use "PadRight"?

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, if  I understand correctly, that case is much easier: you can use `Flatten[Diagonal[array[3], #] & /@ {0, 1, 2}]`

Comment: very helpful answer! thank you!

Comment: how can we get Voigt notation in Mathematica from Fourth Order Tensor ?

Answer (score 5):

Your question does not have a satisfactory answer unless you remove the requirement against a "manual" way.

First, let us define a function that will allow us to translate from `{i,j}` coordinates to `k` coordinates, where the `i` and `j` run from 1 to 3 and `k` runs from 1 to 6.

```
transf[u_] := 
  Simplify[u.{{0, 3 - α}, {α, -3}}.u + {-10, 11}.u];
```

There, `α` is an arbitrary parameter. The call to `Simplify` is not necessary if you pick a value for `α`, say 0. In any case,

```
transf /@ {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}
```

yields

```
{1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 3}
```

Thus, we confirm `transf` is the mapping `{i,j}↦k`. Unfortunately, one cannot solve

```
k == transf[{i, j}]
(*k == (11 - 3 j) j + i (-10 + 3 j)*)
```

to get a "unique" inverse `k↦{i,j}`. For example, if we solve it for the diagonal entries:

```
Solve[k == transf[{i, i}], i]
(*{{i -> k}}*)
```

But for off-diagional entries in the third column:

```
Solve[k == transf[{i, 3}], i]
(*{{i -> 6 - k}}*)
```

So, the map `k↦{i,j}` will necessarily be a piece-wise function that will look as if it was coded by hand.

By the way, I will left it as an exercise for you to prove that the pullback `k↦{i,j}` is necessary to obtain the Voigt components out of the traditional ones.

If you decide to remove the requirement against "manual", then I would advise you to use `Dispatch`.

Comment: as you suggest, (Manual)  is removed now.